# Utility to search pdf bookmarks

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

Is there a utility to search pdf bookmarks across many files?

Comment: What OS? Can you describe your situation?

Comment: [This thread](http://superuser.com/questions/163182/command-line-tool-to-search-phrases-in-large-number-of-pdf-files) mentions a few ways to search across pdf files, but I think none of the methods allow searching specifically in bookmarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Adobe Reader](http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/) can search multiple bookmarks.

> With the advanced search, you can
>   search all PDF files in a directory
>   and its sub-directories in a single
>   go. By default, if you open Adobe
>   Reader and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +
>   <kbd>F</kbd>, you’ll get the normal
>   search box. It is located at the top
>   right in the menu bar.
>
> To use the advanced PDF search option,
>   you can choose **Open Full Reader
>   Search** in the drop down menu of the
>   search box or press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
>
> Go ahead and enter the phrase you are
>   searching for in the search box. Next
>   choose the **All PDF Documents In**
>   option under **Where would you like to
>   search** heading.
>
> [image]
>
> Browse to the folder where all of your
>   PDF documents are stored and then
>   choose the option **Include
>   Bookmarks** (searches the text of any
>   bookmarks, as viewed in the Bookmarks
>   panel).
>
> [image]

Comment: I think I'm looking for a solution that's outside of Adobe Reader that will parse out text for me...