# PDF Text Search & Replace

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to automate a search and replace for text in PDF files.  Are there any programs that let you do that using command line?  Tried A-PDF text replace but it did not work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this when searching for your question and also mine :)

It said Acrobat 9+ provides command-line utilities.

[Command line tool to search phrases in large number of pdf files](https://superuser.com/questions/163182/command-line-tool-to-search-phrases-in-large-number-of-pdf-files)

This is my tactic:

1. convert pdf files to text files.
2. bulk searching and replacing using text utilities, it should be
   simple if you can program.
3. convert edited text files back to pdf files.

Comment: I thought of that but unfortunately the PDFs are not just plain text PDFs.  They contain a lot of images, charts, etc.  I might lose some formatting when converting to text files and back.  I literally just need to find a way I can replace certain text in PDFs with blanks.  So basically just deleting the text.

Comment: Just think about only writing your own program can deal with your issue, if you are a java guy, this library http://pdfbox.apache.org/ can help you access and extract for text.